# Matrix-based css transform rotation interpolations are "wrong" on -webkit?

Tags: javascript, css, matrix, transition

I'm multiplying a identity matrix by 90 degree rotation matrix (1.57079633 rad) using sylvester.js and applying the results to css transform matrix3d property.

**Identity matrix:**

```
var identityMatrix = $M([
  [1,0,0,0],
  [0,1,0,0],
  [0,0,1,0],
  [0,0,0,1]
]);
```

**RotationMatrix:**

```
var rotationYMatrix = $M([
      [Math.cos( 1.57079633), 0, Math.sin(1.57079633),0],
      [0,1,0,0],
      [Math.sin(-1.57079633), 0, Math.cos(1.57079633), 0],
      [0,0,0,1]
    ]);
```

First time I multiply all goes well and the plane as expected rotates 90 clockwise (0-90). But when i multiply again it takes the longest path counterclockwise from 90 to 180. What am I doing wrong? A code is here http://jsfiddle.net/W5Ks8/81/ - just click the button once, wait for the animation to stop and click again.

I have read this [chrome issue](http://w3-org.9356.n7.nabble.com/css-transitions-Some-matrix-based-rotation-interpolations-are-quot-wrong-quot-td253984.html) and maybe it applies to my case, but in my scenario I need to use css matrix3d and some solution/suggestion (even if it's dirty) would be appreciated.